# What is causing TableLayout contents to disappear?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-widget

I've created a view that extends TableLayout.  The number of columns is determined by an XML attribute.  I have a method on the view that takes a list as input, and builds the table rows and cells dynamically (inlates a row layout, adds it, inflates cell layouts, adds those to the rows), and does a few other housekeeping things - it's pretty simple.

```
public class MyTable extends TableLayout {
   private int columns = 1;

   public MyTable(Context context) {
     this(context,null);
   }

   public MyTable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context,attrs);
      if (attrs != null) {
         TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(atters, R.styleable.MyTable);
         if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.MyTable_columns)) {
            columns = a.getInt(R.styleable.MyTable_columns, 1);
            this.setWeightSum(columns);
         }
         a.recycle();
      }
   }

   public void populate(List<x> items) {
       // remove any children, if this was already populated.
       this.removeAllViews();
       if (items == null || items.size == 0) {
          // nothing to do here.
          return;
       }
       int rows = 1;
       if (items.size() > columns) {
         rows = Math.max(1, items.size / columns + items.size() % columns);
       }
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
       for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
          TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row,this,false);
          this.addView(tableRow);
          int start = (i-1)*columns;
          int end = Math.min(items.size()-1,(i * columns)-1);
          for (;start <=end;start++) {
             LinearLayout cell = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cell,tableRow,false);
             tableRow.addView(cell);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

I'm using that widget inside of a fragment.  The layout for that fragment includes an instance of my widget, and it seems to work just fine - I pass in my list, the table gets populated, everything's hunky dory - until I take an action that causes another component in the view to be hidden. For example I have a button that does some stuff, and then set's itself to View.GONE.  When that occurs, my table layout disappears from the view.  If I perform another action that modifies visibility of another component, it comes back, and after that it seems to stick around.  I've triple checked, and I am not setting the visibility on the MyTable, and I've even gone so far as to override setVisibility() to log - and it's not getting called at all.

What could be going on here?

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the on-screen keyboard. If the keyboard is shown, then hidden, then it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was wrapping the everything up in a scrollview that was set with android:height="match_parent" rather than wrap_content. Changed that, and it works fine.